# Visual Studio 2015 revert Class View layout change, after installing Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Since I've installed Xamarin tools for Visual Studio 2015, the layout of the Class View looks like this:

[image]

It's a different layout than the normal Class View layout. How would I be able to change it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings**.
Before you do this, be sure to **BackUp all your settings** too.